# Can I get HTML column titles within a data.frame/renderTable?

Tags: r, shiny

I am using the `renderTable(data.frame('x'=1))` syntax to produce a nice interactive table, but I can't make the column names render as HTML.

Full MWE:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderUI(
      renderTable(data.frame('want_html_<sub>here</sub>'=1:3))
      )
    }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I've tried wrapping the `'want_hmtl_here'` string in `HTML()`.

Is rendering HTML possible with this setup or do I need to use a full htmlTable like in: [Display reactive htmlTable table in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255622/display-reactive-htmltable-table-in-shiny)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderTable({
    data.frame('want_html_<sub>here</sub>' = 1:3, check.names = FALSE)
  }, sanitize.colnames.function = function(x) x)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```